# Why my code no Insert into some tables?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to create a row in every table for user that just register and the `id` must be the same as the one in `users` tables. And im trying to using `$mysqli->insert_id` method but it didnt work. The code only `INSERT INTO` my users table... Can anyone tell me the problem with my code and explain `$mysqli->insert_id`, please? :(

Thanks.

PHP CODE

```
<?php
include_once("../init.php");

if (isset($_POST)) {
$username       = trim($_POST['username']);
$password       = crypt(trim($_POST['password']), 'st');
$email          = trim($_POST['email']);
$email_code     = md5($username + microtime());
$insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, email_code, created) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
$insert_stmt->bind_param('ssss', $username, $password, $email, $email_code);
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        } else {
            $whatajoke = $insert_stmt->insert_id;   
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO login_attempts (id) VALUES ('$whatajoke')");
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO personal_detail (id, username) VALUES ('$whatajoke', '$username')");
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ip (id) VALUES ('$whatajoke')");
            //email('htmlemail.php');
            header('Location: ../register_success.php');
        }
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: where you call new mysqli?

Comment: `$whatajoke = $insert_stmt->insert_id;   `

Comment: you don't have somthing like $insert_stmt = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world"); ?

Comment: Why don't you read the manual first?! You should not ask on SO, just because you are too lazy to read the manual.

Answer (score 1):

`insert_id` only makes sense after executing the insert query. You are using it before. Another condition is that your table has an auto increment column.

How it works : PHP sends the query to mysql, mysql inserts the line and assigns a value to the auto incremented id column. If you need this id to be able to refer to the new record later in the code, you use `insert_id`.